# ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: xubuntu, python3, cuda

I am getting this error when I want to import tensorflow-gpu on Ubuntu 16.04.

I have installed CUDA 9.1 properly, cudNN 7.1 properly and tested both without facing any problem. (using python 3.5 2.)

I have used pip3 in either ways (with several tensorflow versions):
i tried:

```
#for tensoflow 1.4
pip3 install tensorflow-gpu==1.4
# for tensorflow 1.8 from source
pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.8.0rc1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

I have tried to install several versions of tensorflow-gpu , 1.4, 1.5 , 1.8 ,1.9.
 still getting the same error, when running

```
import tensorflow as tf 

ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is there any way to get rid of this? or it is just installing cuda 9.0 ( which will be the pain as it took a week for me to install the cuda 9.1 due to problems of nvidia and Ubuntu !)

I also installed libcupti (required) and Bazel (required).
from this page:
http://www.python36.com/install-tensorflow141-gpu/2/

moreover, i have installed the same setup on windows (tensorflow 1.8 , cuda 9.1) without any problem.

Comment: Hello  Omid, and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. In order to increase that chances that somebody gives a good answer to your question, the first thing to do is ask a question; you should edit your post and actually include a question. You should also clarify the context: who gives that error message? When does it give that error message? What are you doing in order to make that error message appear? Is the error message unexpected? If so, what were you expecting to happen?

Comment: you should enclose the commands you used.

Comment: i tried:
pip3 install tensorflow-gpu==1.4
pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.8.0rc1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl

Comment: libcublas9.1 is in the 18.04 repositories and you have CUDA 9.1 installed so why don't you manually download [libcublas9.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libcublas9.1/download) and double-click it to open it for installation in Ubuntu Software.

Comment: @karel OP said their system is 16.04.

Comment: @avazula I know it's 16.04 so you can't use apt, but you can still download libcublas9.1_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb manually and install it.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought that since it's a `.deb` associated with 18.04, it wouldn't be compatible with 16. My bad. :)

Comment: @Omid Have you uninstalled the previous CUDA version before trying to install the new one?

Comment: Although, i didnt install previous versions (just installed ubuntu 16.04). 
But how may I check it if these is older(other) versions?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to build `tensorflow-gpu 1.4`, which is too old to be compatible with CUDA 9.1.

From here you have three options:

1. You can try to create a symbolic link to force the system to use CUDA 9.1, though it's not sure it'll succeed
2. You can follow [this tutorial](https://yangcha.github.io/CUDA90/) which explains how to easily install CUDA 9.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.
3. If it still doesn't work and that you *really* want to try to install Tensorflow with CUDA 9.1, you can try to install [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-zone), [CUDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn) and [NCCL](https://developer.nvidia.com/nccl) sources from the NVIDIA site, and then emulate the way these packages would have been installed from ppa.

Once you've downloaded the `tar` packages, type the following to configure CUDA:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/cuda /usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI /usr/local/cuda/nvvm
sudo ln -s /usr/bin /usr/local/cuda/bin
sudo ln -s /usr/include /usr/local/cuda/include
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/local/cuda/lib64
sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda/lib64 /usr/local/cuda/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/include /usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/include
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/libdevice /usr/local/cuda/nvvm/libdevice
```

Then you can either download cuDNN and NCCL from source and configure them in the same fashion as above ([this article here](https://medium.com/@asmello/how-to-install-tensorflow-cuda-9-1-into-ubuntu-18-04-b645e769f01d) explains how to do so), or download their `.deb` package and see if the installation works now. If it doesn't, then try to install from source.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81479/discussion-on-answer-by-avazula-importerror-libcublas-so-9-0-cannot-open-share).